# Configuring include-search for PHP

Tags: vimrc, search, include, filetype-php

I just learned of the existence of [include-search](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/navigating-code-projects-without-using-external-commands/2862#2862), but even after reading `:help include-search`and `:help includeexpr` I'm not sure what I need to do to have `[I` find included and required files.

**How do I configure include-search for both included and required PHP files?**

I *think* I need to set `includeexpr` such that it allow searching files whether they were included using `require`, `require_once`, `include`, or `include_once`; but I'm not sure. And I don't quite get what the variable is supposed to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default php ftplugin already does that for you:

```
setlocal include=\\\(require\\\|include\\\)\\\(_once\\\)\\\?
```

Add `filetype plugin indent on` to your `~/.vimrc` if it's not already there to benefit from Vim's filetype detection.